# Can I reconstruct System of equation when given Solution set and constants?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

We have 3 equations  $$ 2x+7y+1z = 20$$  $$2x + y + 6z = 28$$ $$3x +2y +5z = 27$$

the constants for this will  $ \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 2\\ 4 \end{pmatrix} $

So if I was given constants  $ \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 2\\ 4 \end{pmatrix} $  and Solution   $ \begin{pmatrix} 20  \\ 28 \\ 27 \end{pmatrix} $ Can I able to to get back to the coefficients (reconstruct the equations) and also if given range that coefficients will range between 1
to 7 and are integers?

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't have enough information. Let's suppose you even know the second and the third equations, and all you need is to find some $a,b,c$ such that $$a\cdot1+b\cdot2+c\cdot4=20$$
Obviously $a=2, b=7, c=1$ is a solution, but so is $a=20, b=c=0$ or $a=2, b=1, c=4$.

Comment: We have some limitations for a,b,c they should be between  1 and 7 and are integers.

Comment: Even then you have many solutions. Here are a few more $(a,b,c)$ triplets: $(4,4,2)$, $(6,3,2)$, $(6,5,1)$. How do you decide which one is the one you want?